# hosting web app

Tags: php

still new in php this being my second app and i decided to try implement it so i downloaded a template and linked it to the same file and tried hosting it but the online app will not open, instead it downloads a php file. I have tried all other options i could get via web resources but none is working for me. I am using a free domain which refers to the link to my index file for the html website in my dropbox public file

the website is [www.kenyandrive.tk](http://www.kenyandrive.tk) and the online test is where the web app is linked...use user,user to login

Comment: Sounds to me like your hosting provider does not have PHP capabilities. Free domains will rarely give you anything beyond static HTML hosting (not always the case but generally true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems PHP interpreter is not configured properly or simply you don't have that option with your hosting. Try contact the the hosting for more information about their services to see if they provide the tools you need. 
Even if it is a free hosting they usually offer PHP capabilities, check if it is something simple like the *.php extension in your file.

Comment: the domain is pulling the files from dropbox not server which i assume interpretation is supposed to be implemented there...any easy ways or apps to connect to server by using this free domains?